# Return more than one value in list vb.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

Before telling you the problem, excuse me for my bad english, I only know the basic
I have a function with a query and I want to return it, I was doing this:

```
Public Function obtenerDataAjuste(ByVal id As Integer)
     Dim ajuste As New Ajuste
     Dim cmd as New SqlCommand("usp_obtenerDataAjuste",cn.getCN")
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
     cn.getCN().Open()
     Dim dr as SqlDataReader
     dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
     Dim ajustelist As New List(Of Ajuste)
     While dr.Read
         ajuste.pesomix = dr("PesoMix")
         ajuste.pesoprod = dr("PesoProd")
         ajuste.unidad = dr("UNIDAD_EMPAQUE")
     End While
     cn.getCN().Close()
     Return ajustelist.ToArray
End Function
```

but I think is wrong because I was calling this function into my code behind:

```
Dim opd As New OPDAO
    For Each objAjuste In opd.obtenerDataAjuste(CInt(Session("idop")))
        Dim pesomix As Decimal = objAjuste.pesomix
        Dim pesoprod As Decimal = objAjuste.pesoprod
        Dim empaque As Integer = objAjuste.unidad

        'Reajuste unidad ajustado
        Dim unidadajustado As Double = pesomix / pesoprod
        Session("undajustado") = Convert.ToInt32(unidadajustado)

        'Reajuste paquete ajustado
        Dim paqueteajustado As Double = Session("undajustado") / empaque
        Session("pqtajustado") = paqueteajustado

    Next
```

and it doesn't work for me, it returns the last record. Can anyone help me please?.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the `id` parameter for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not adding anything to your list. You also need to initialize a new `Ajuste` object **inside** the `While dr.Read` loop.

That's the reason why you only see the last value right now, because you constantly overwrite your `Ajuste` object that you initialised **outside** the while loop.

```
  Dim ajustelist As New List(Of Ajuste)
         While dr.Read
             Dim ajuste As New Ajuste       // <-- add this
             ajuste.pesomix = dr("PesoMix")
             ajuste.pesoprod = dr("PesoProd")
             ajuste.unidad = dr("UNIDAD_EMPAQUE")
             ajustelist.Add(ajuste)         // <-- and this
         End While
```

Comment: Hi Jane Doe, You're right, that was my error. Thank you so much, this is my first time in stackoverflow and it was so usefull for me! thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Each time through the For Each loop, you will overwrite what you previously put into Session("undajustado") which will end up being the last item in the loop when its done.

I need to know what you are trying to accomplish before being able to help you.